# cv2.videoCapture(filename) assigning filename dynamically (Closed)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, face-recognition, raw-input

I am trying to access `file_name` dynamically from user and then pass it to `videoCapture(file_name)` and then process it.

Code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import sqlite3
import pickle
from PIL import Image
import sys


faceDetect = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml');
rec = cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer();


'''
Dynamically accessing the fileName

Error seems to be here in the following couple of codes
Note: i am assigning file_name as <"test.mp4">
'''
file_name = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
print file_name


cam = cv2.VideoCapture(file_name)

while cam.isOpened():
    ret,img = cam.read()

    if ret == True:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)        
        faces = faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5);
        for(x,y,w,h) in faces :
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
            id,conf=rec.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
            '''
            Few lines of code
            '''

        cv2.imshow("Face",img);
        if (cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q')):
            break;
    else :
        print ('ret is false')
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

it show no error but it does not execute the `while(cam.isOpened):` loop. am i missing something ?

Comment: if you hardcode the filename works?

Comment: yes. it works fine if cam = cv2.VideoCapture(file_name) is replaced with cam = cv2.VideoCapture("test.mp4").

Comment: Tried your code on my machine, worked fine. What does ret say ? is it true or not ? I have previously observed VideoCapture does not throw error for many cases.

Comment: do not know that 'ret' is.

output :
enter file name : **"test.mp4"** __<i have kept the double quotation>__

>> "test.mp4"

Comment: ret is the variable in your code. You have to enter file name without quotes. Try that it works fine.

Comment: @harshkn Thank you ! its working now.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the filename without the quotes. It works fine. Because since the input has alphabets it will be string object already. Adding quotes will be like inputting a wrong file name. As I said in comments videocapture does not throw error sometimes if entered filename does not exist. Hope this helps